# Import Module failed, may need an additional loader

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I am trying to use this module: https://github.com/kainino0x/glslang.js but the browser says I may need additional loaders. I used npm to install it and the module can be found in the node_modules just fine. I can also access type definitions in "/@webgpu/glslang/dist/web-devel/glslang.d.ts". Here is the code where I try to import the module:

```
import GLModule, {Glslang} from "@webgpu/glslang/dist/web-devel/glslang";

async function compileGlslToSpirV(glslCode: string) {
  const glsl:Glslang = await GLModule();
  return glsl.compileGLSL(glslCode, "compute", true);
}
```

Here is the browser error code:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (913:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       Module({
|         locateFile() {
>           const i = import.meta.url.lastIndexOf('/');
|           return import.meta.url.substring(0, i) + '/glslang.wasm';
|         },
```

Here is the type definition for glslang.d.ts:

```
declare type SpirvVersion = '1.0' | '1.1' | '1.2' | '1.3' | '1.4' | '1.5';

declare interface ResultZeroCopy {
    readonly data: Uint32Array;
    free(): void;
}

declare interface Glslang {
    compileGLSLZeroCopy(glsl: string, shader_stage: ShaderStage, gen_debug: boolean, spirv_version?: SpirvVersion): ResultZeroCopy;
    compileGLSL(glsl: string, shader_type: ShaderStage, gen_debug: boolean, spirv_version?: SpirvVersion): Uint32Array;
}

export default function(): Promise<Glslang>;
```

I managed to use another way to import the module using dynamic imports so I know that the module works fine on its own. I would prefer not having to do that though and I would like to understand how to import glslang to access the compileGLSL function. I am pretty sure that I need to install a tool to import the Module but I have no idea which one.

Just in case here is my package.json:

````
{
  "name": "typescript-redux-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "@webgpu/glslang": "0.0.15",
    "@webgpu/types": "0.0.34",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.1",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
} ```

Thank you very much.
````